# Is there any way to run webdriver.io selenium tests against a chrome extension?

Tags: node.js, selenium, webdriver-io

I'm thinking something along the lines of

```
capabilities: [
    {
        maxInstances: 1,
        browser: "Chrome",
        name: "Chrome"
    },
    {
        maxInstances: 1,
        browser: "Chrome",
        options: "myIeExtension",
        name: "IE"
    }
]
```

The name bit is optional but would be really handy.

Edit:
Currently I've got

```
const fs = require('fs');
function encode(file) {
    const stream = fs.readFileSync(file);
    return Buffer.from(stream).toString('base64');
}

capabilities: [
{
  maxInstances: 1,
  browserName: 'chrome',
  chromeOptions: { extensions: [encode('path_to_my_crx_file/my_extension.crx')] },
}
],
```

which works, but each time I run the selenium tests I have to go through the extension intro - enter email, password, select this that and launch.  Is there any way to get round having to have selenium enter all these values as part of the test?

Answer (score 0):

So you can do it as above specifying the path to the chrome extension in ChromeOptions.  However you have to set it up every time.

Alternatively just use the default profile:

```
  capabilities: [
{
  maxInstances: 1,
  browserName: 'chrome',
  chromeOptions: { args: ['user-data-dir=/home/<username>/.config/google-chrome'] },
},
```

You won't have to set up the extension every time you use it, you just have to do it once and then it'll just be there.